# React Select tag: 2nd select tag option values depends on the 1st select tag selected values

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 select tags in my react project.

[image]

So the first one is the "Customer" and the second one is "Project" and the option is from an API.

```
   <Form.Group as = {Col}>
                    <Form.Label className ="form-label">
                          Customer
                    </Form.Label>
                          <Form.Control 
                           value={values} 
                           onChange={(e)=> setValues(e.target.value)}
                           as="select">
                                <option>--Select--</option>
                                <FetchAPI/>
                          </Form.Control>
              </Form.Group>
              <br/>
              <Form.Group as = {Col}>
                    <Form.Label>Project</Form.Label>
                          <Form.Control  value = {project} onChange={(e)=> setProject(e.target.value)}as="select">
                                 <option>--Select--</option>
                                <FetchAPI/>
                          </Form.Control>
              </Form.Group>
```

What I want to do now is to set the "Project" select's option values to be displayed based on the "Customer" selected values.

For example:
"Customer": Customer 1
"Project": 'Display all the values that are related to Customer 1 (Project1 etc.)'

FetchAPI codes:

```
  const[data, SetData] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;capital;currencies')
        .then(response=>{
              console.log(response)
              SetData(response.data)
        })
  })
  return (
        <>
              {data.map(apiData =>(
              <option >{apiData.name}</option>
              ))}   
        </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to filter the response based on selected Customer

example :

```
    <FetchAPI values={values}/>
```

In your  Component

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

        // Which is the selected customer


    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;capital;currencies')
        .then(response=>{
            const projects =  response.data.filter((project) => {
                project.name === props.values
            })
            SetData(projects)
        })

    
    }, [props.values])
```

Comment: Does this method for multiple links like I am using the JSONPlaceHolder API data like this:

For example:
Customer = users, Project = todos.

Something like this

Comment: yup..  It can be used for multiple links

Comment: But now the output shows an error that is about no-unused-expressions" but I already assigned it in my FetchAPI function and the props in my form as well

Comment: can you produce it on CodeSandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cdn-rm8it?file=/src/App.js

Comment: See console log you have an infinite fetching

Comment: cause by FetchAPIUserID -> useEffect

Comment: I edited you code https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-butterfly-hmpuc?file=/src/FetchAPI.js

Comment: I edited a little bit, just to show the logic of what I want to do:
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cdn-rm8it?file=/src/FetchAPI.js

but still doesn't show the output like is still empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231915/discussion-between-yong-kevin-and-abu-dujana-mahalail).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hertz-jkl4z?file=/src/FetchAPI.js -> edited

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this is pass the selected Customer into the `<FetchAPI/>` call within the Project section so the `FetchAPI` component can determine which options to return to the Project dropdown.

Comment: Hi, I make some edits to the post. As the FetchAPI is just fetching the data.
Some my idea is to use an If-Else but not sure how to do it